# Question about gcd and integer solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given $\gcd(x, y, z) = 1$, $\ a,b,c \gt 2; \ \ x,y,z \gt 1$, is it possible to find $r$ and $s$ such that $rx^a + sy^b = 1$, but $y^b \nmid z^cr - 1$, or $x^a \nmid z^cs - 1$?

My attempt.

Since $\gcd(x,y,z) = 1$, we have $\gcd(x^a, y^b, z^c) = 1$.   Let $X = x^a, Y = y^b$, etc. be notation.

Then if we have
$$
r_0 X + s_0 Y = 1 \\
r_1 X + s_1 Z = 1 \\
r_2 Y + s_2 Z = 1
$$
then take the first one together with Beal's equation to yield
$$
Z(r_0 X + s_0 Y = 1) \text{ and } X + Y = Z \\
\implies
(r_0 Z - 1)X + (s_0 Z - 1)Y = 0
$$
since $\gcd(X,Y) = 1$, we have
$$
  Y \mid (r_0 Z - 1) \text{  and  } X \mid (s_0 Z -1)
$$
Then let's rewrite the set of equations above with some improvements:
$$
r_0 X + s_0 Y = 1 \\
r_1 X + s_0 Z = 1 \\
r_2 Y + r_0 Z = 1
$$
In other words, such $r$'s and $s$'s exist as integers.

We immediately have that $(r_0 - r_1)X = s_0(Z-Y)$, so $s_0 = r_0 - r_1$.

Comment: What have you tried? In particular, this would be a trivial consequence of the same proposition for $a=b=c=1$. Does the latter hold? I have no idea myself, but maybe you do...

Comment: Some refinement will be needed. You don't want $y=1$. Also $\gcd(x,y,z)=1$ does not exclude $\gcd)x,t)\gt 1$.